# UIImage saved in CoreData is not the same after loading

Tags: swift, core-data, uiimage

I have a CoreData entity that has a *uiImage* property, of type 'binary data' that is supposed to hold a *Data* object representing a *UIImage*.

I am saving the image in *CoreData* before making sure that it's the correct image, but debugging and looking at it with the preview button:

[image]

This is how I save the image in *CoreData*:

```
let myEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "MyEntity", into: context) as! MyEntity
let uiImage = ... // The image that I was able to inspect with a preview
myEntity.uiImage = uiImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
...
try context.save()
```

Then I fetch the image later with this code:

```
let context = PersistentContainer.shared.container.viewContext
let request = NSFetchRequest<SaliencyImage>(entityName: "MyEntity")
request.predicate = NSPredicate(
    // This is the key that I use to identity my entity
    format: "assetId == %@", assetId 
)
let myEntity = try context.fetch(request).first
let uiImage = UIImage(data: myEntity.uiImage!)!
```

But if I inspect the image, this is what I get in a preview:

[image]

Like you can see, only the top left corner is saved/fetched. Even though I made sure that the image was the correct one before saving it in *CoreData*. Does anybody have an explanation/solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is at below line.

```
let myEntity = try context.fetch(request).first
```

You are just taking first record of the image. There are more. So you have to for loop for the same.

Code should be as below.

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: 'Your Entity Name')
do {
  result = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
  for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
    storedImageData.append(data.value(forKey: "storedImage") as! Data)
  }
} catch let error as NSError {
  print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
}
let image = UIImage(data: storedImageData)
```

[Reference](https://blog.devgenius.io/saving-images-in-coredata-8739690d0520)

Comment: That doesn’t make sense. Core Data doesn’t automatically create multiple instances and split up the data like that. Even if it did, that code doesn’t sort the results of the fetch, so the data chunks would be out of order.